# Given Area, find Width and Height

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an area A, find an optimal rectangle. An optimal rectangle would have the property, where the length to width ratio is as small as possible. (All calculations to be done in integer)

Basically, I was solving this coding challenge: 
https://leetcode.com/problems/construct-the-rectangle/#/description

And i've solved it, as many others with an iterative approach.

```
    w = int(math.sqrt(area))
    while(area%w!=0):
        w -= 1

    return [area/w, w]
```

So given 4 the right answer would be 2,2. Given 8: 4,2.

Anyone a solution without iteratively finding w?

Thanks and sorry if i am using wrong math terms.

Comment: One way would be to come up with a list of factors of $area$ in sorted order, then pick the first factor less than $\sqrt{area}$. But I suspect that'll be a lot more compute intensive in most cases. It'll definitely be more code intensive, unless you have a function available that can compute the factors in order for you.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, you need to find the factors of A. The factors closest to sqrt(A) are the solution. This is basically what you did, but instead of factoring you just checked all nearby values.
Since the problem requires integer solutions, you must factor. This requires iteration (or some weird recursive method). So you basically have to use iteration somehow.